# how to select rows in a dataframe which are not in a pandas series array?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'y':[7,8,9,10,11,12]})
index=pd.Series([2,5])
```

how can I select the rows in `df` using the indices that are *not* in `index`?

`df.loc[~index,:]` and `df.loc[not(index),:]` do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `df[~df.index.isin(index)]`. Now remember that dataframe start at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of function for index `difference`

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(index)]
   x   y
0  1   7
1  2   8
3  4  10
4  5  11
```